# Node postgres query update results before returning

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a simple call to a postgres db. (Select * from users) when this returns I want to add a property to the results. This appears to work correctly in the console I see the new property but the return value when I test in postman doesn't have the new property. How can I do this?

```
    const res = await client.query(query);
    res.rows.Summary=[8,56,77];
    console.log(res.rows);
    return res.rows;

// from console.log

[
    {
        "userid": "79",
        "firstname": "fred",
        "lastname": "jimerson",
         
    },
    {
        "userid": "9",
        "firstname": "Cory",
        "lastname": "",
      
    },
  Summary: [ 8, 56, 77 ] ]
   
]


/// Results from postman


[
    {
        "userid": "79",
        "firstname": "fred",
        "lastname": "jimerson",
         
    },
    {
        "userid": "9",
        "firstname": "Cory",
        "lastname": "",
      
    } 
   
]
```

Comment: are you sure query returns object ?

Comment: Can you post result ?

Comment: Seems it was invalid to just add the way I did creating an object worked. So essentially what you said. 
const res = await client.query(query);
 var comp={rows:res.rows,summary:[8,56,77]};